# How to insert the value of ascii?

Tags: android

How can I insert to my TextView the value of ascii arrow down?

for example:

I found that the ascii of arrow down = `&#x25B2`

`myText.setText(&#x25B2);`

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
myText.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#x25B2"));
```